# CentOS 7 ошибка ядра unregister_netdevice: waiting for lo to become free. Usage count = 1

Tags: linux, centos, docker, centos7

Всем привет, прошу помочь. Сегодня на сервере выскочила ошибка:

> unregister_netdevice: waiting for lo to become free. Usage count = 1

после чего пришлось ребутать машину. Нагуглил, что проблема с версией ядра Docker, но пути решений так и не удалось найти.

Comment: сервер чего у вас? железо или вас?

Comment: @Hellseher виртуала на CentOS 7

Comment: лог от куда у вас? дайте хоть наводку `/var/log`

Comment: @Hellseher /var/log/messages